# How to access the state of one component or the constants of one component in another component (not parent child) - React

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am working on React Table. I am basically a beginner in React. I have a dashboard page where I display a React Table of 8 columns. I have a customize button which will open a popup page, this popup page has 8 check boxes allows me to show/hide those React columns. Initially all the check boxes in this popup page is set to true. When I uncheck a column that particular column get disabled.

[image]

This is the code for the popup page for checkbox

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ActionCreators } from '../../../actions';
import ButtonComponent from '../../common/button/ButtonComponent';
import { CheckBox } from '../../common/chkbox/CheckBox';

class CustomizedView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCheckChildElement = this.handleCheckChildElement.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { id: 1, value: 'Column 1', isChecked: true },
        { id: 2, value: 'Column 2', isChecked: true },
        { id: 3, value: 'Column 3', isChecked: true },
        { id: 4, value: 'Column 4', isChecked: true },
        { id: 5, value: 'Column 5', isChecked: true },
        { id: 6, value: 'Column 6', isChecked: true },
        { id: 7, value: 'Column 7', isChecked: true },
        { id: 8, value: 'Column 8', isChecked: true },
      ]
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked });
  }

  handleCheckChildElement(event) {
    const { items } = this.state; //extract state values like this to a const variable
    const newItems = items.map((item) => { //do map on items because map returns a new array. It’s good practice to use .map than forEach in your case
      if(item.value === event.target.value) {
        item.isChecked = event.target.checked;
        return item; //return updated item object so that it will be pushed to the newItems array
      }
      return item; // return item because you need this item object as well
    });
    this.setState({ items: newItems }); //finally set newItems array into items
    const column1checked = items[0].isChecked;
    console.log('column1checked ' + column1checked);
    const column2checked = items[1].isChecked;
    console.log('column2checked ' + column2checked);
    const column3checked = items[2].isChecked;
    console.log('column3checked ' + column3checked);
    const column4checked = items[3].isChecked;
    console.log('column4checked ' + column4checked);
    const column5checked = items[4].isChecked;
    console.log('column5checked ' + column5checked);
    const column6checked = items[5].isChecked;
    console.log('column6checked ' + column6checked);
    const column7checked = items[6].isChecked;
    console.log('column7checked ' + column7checked);
    const column8checked = items[7].isChecked;
    console.log('column8checked ' + column8checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='div-container-custom' >
        <div className='bottomBar'>
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Apply'
            className='activeButton filterMargin-custom'
            width='100'
            display='inline-block'
            onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(this.state, false); }}
          />
          <ButtonComponent
            text='Clear Filter'
            className='greyedButton clear-custom-filter'
            width='100'
            display='block'
            marginTop='60'
            onClick={() => { this.props.applyFilter(this.state, true); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className='data-points-text'>
            <span> Columns </span>
          </div>
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
              {
                this.state.items.map((item, i) => {
                  return (<div key={i} ><CheckBox handleCheckChildElement={this.handleCheckChildElement} {...item} /></div>);
                })
              };
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CustomizedView.propTypes = {
  applyFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

CustomizedView.defaultProps = {
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedView);
```

I am a complete beginner in React and I need help from this community. Kindly help to implement this idea.

Can I transfer the constants (true/false) or should transfer the state. I want to transfer the boolean value for each columns  from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview to components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

Please look carefully. Notice the lines after

```
this.setState({ items: newItems });
```

I tried exporting the constants but got error. I think React does not allow us to export constants. If I transfer the state, how should I fetch the state from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview to components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

It should be noted this components are not Parent - Child. You can check the file paths.

Being a beginner I have no idea about Redux. Though I have the Redux connect but I don't know how to use this. So how can I access the state from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview in components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedView);
```

So I have mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
}
```

I just need to transfer the 8 flags/booleans from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview to components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

Comment: I don't see `ReactTableComponent` being used as a child of `CustomizedView`. Is that correct? If so, you're going to need to some some shared state either in a component that sits above both of them, or in a central global store (a Redux store being a common example)

Comment: @Matthew Herbst  Yes they are not parent - child. Also there are no component that sits above both of them. So what should I do? You can see the file path

Comment: @Matthew Herbst I do not know Redux. I am a complete beginner.

Comment: You should learn how to make a global store. Redux is the most popular tool by far used to do that. I suggest you take a look at it, unless you are interested in writing your own which can be done, though generally you'll want to understand how Flux works first: https://facebook.github.io/flux/

Comment: @Matthew Herbst  Are there any easier ways apart from this?

Comment: @Matthew Herbst  I already written this export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomizedView) .Will it do the job?

Comment: @Matthew Herbst I already have the Redux connect. So how can I access the state from components\abcdashboard\customized_view\Customizedview in components\common\react_table\ReactTableComponent

Comment: There's no easier way really unfortunately. You want data stored above your two components, and you want your components to update when that data is changed. For your Redux, you'll need both components connected to the store. When you want to change data in the store you will `dispatch` an Action with a payload. Then one of your Reducers will create a new store state, and your other component will receive an update through `connect` when the store state changes.

Comment: @Matthew Herbst  Can we use global variables in React for this purpose instead of difficult things like Redux for example env file?

Comment: @Matthew Herbst Can we use local storage instead of Redux ?

Comment: Where you store the data is not the problem. You can store it anywhere you want. The hard part is making sure your components re-render/update when the "global" store changes in a manner that would impact how they render.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can achieve your use case in 2 ways. I will explain this with state/props and will avoid Redux for 2 reasons:
First, you mentioned you're a beginner in Redux so don't want to confuse you more But more importantly, wanna show you much more things than you think is achievable without redux. 
I will explain the theory with code snippets but implementation will remain for you.

Suppose you have a component named `App`. This will host your `Customizedview` + `ReactTableComponent`.

Exporting a const from a component or even your state is anti pattern in react.
Instead pass a prop to `Customizedview` named `onCheckBoxChange`.

Your `Customizedview` will call this props whenever a checkbox is changed and will return state of all checkboxes on it.

The `App` component will store it on it's own state named `checkedItems` and pass it two the `ReactTableComponent` as prop. Code snippet below:

```
export default class App extends Component {
 state = {
   checkedItems: [
    { id: checkbox1, checked: true},
    { id: checkbox2, checked: true},
    { id: checkbox3, checked: true},
    { id: checkbox4, checked: true},
   ]
 }
 render () {
    return (
     <App>
      <Customizedview
         onCheckboxChange={checkedItems => this.setState({checkedItems})}
      />

      <Customizedview 
        checkedItems={this.state.checkedItems}
      />
     </App>
     );
  }
}
```

If you have any difficulty comment please.